# debugging crash errors on app launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am getting the following crash when I run the app on my device, but it works fine on the simulator:

[image]

Any idea of where I should probably start looking? This is super abstract to me
Also it seems that every time I run the app, I am getting a different error. 
Here's a bigger image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diO00.png)

Comment: Image is too small to make out. Check the logs on the device it's crashing on via the Organizer, that will have more info.

Comment: hmm..it turns out it's also crashing on the simulator

Comment: Set up exception breakpoint and you will see where is a problem

Comment: Set up the breakpoints n see after which line, does the program is crashing, post the line here if u can. You cant expect an answer without posting any code..:p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of zombie. Put the exception breakpoint in xcode and analyse.

In case if you don't know how to put exception breakpoint follow below steps:

1. Press cmd + 6 to open breakpoint navigator
2. Tap on "+" put present at the bottom left of the screen and select "Add Exception Breakpoint..."
3. Press Done.
4. Now run the program.

The program stops at the point where the exception is thrown. Analyse the problem and fix it.